# Picture from dc to Word document

Tags: c++, mfc, ms-word, gdi

I want to add a picture to my opened word file. But not from file. I have some picture on a DC in my program and want it directly to Word document. Does anybody know how?

At least may be some documents to read advises.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doing a direct injection into Microsoft Word would probably be tricky and break the model people are used to.  I would suggest adding a "copy to clipboard" function in your app, and then letting the user paste it.  That would be more flexible and work with more programs.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vcgeneral/thread/92ddee54-9711-4224-8ff4-e886b8cdb816

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are able to get an IDispatch pointer to the Word document you plan on inserting the picture on...

Once you have that, you can select the Range you want... Once you have a Range the basic code in VB (which you can translate into C++) is:

Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture("yourfile.png")

Yes, I know you said you didn't have a file or didn't want to use one, but I recommend you create a temporary file, insert it into Word, and then delete it when you're done.

Use the [CxImage library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1300/CxImage) on codeproject.com to save your image to disk--assuming you know how to get a HBITMAP or CBitmap of the image you want to save/put into Word.

Comment: Yeah I think I'm going to make something like that, because no useful information have found. I have no problems with saving or adding file to opened word documents. But, thanks for respond.